# Mixing sepfootnotes, endnotes and subfiles and declaring notecontents within subfiles

Tags: endnotes, subfiles

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`sepfootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes)

I'm using a "mix" of sepfootnotes, endnotes and subfiles in an
arrangement like that of the MWE below. The actual project is eleven
chapters by now (so a few files) and I'd like to keep the note content i the chapter-/subfiles.

I would like to declare the `\sepfootnotecontent` in the top of each
chapter like the `\sepfootnotecontent{a}{In subfile.}` in the
subfile. Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get a message 
`'a' has not been assigned a content on input line 4.`.

In the resulting PDF, the footnote content of foot note no one is
(obciously) empty whereas note no 2 and 3 look as expected.

I've been reading the `sepfootnotes.sty` file but I'm not getting it.
The `subfiles`package is simply `input`ing the subfile so what is the 
actual difference between the first and third note with respect to
sepfootnotes.

I'm wondering why this is and whether there's a solution.

`subfiles-sepfootnotes.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles,sepfootnotes}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\begin{document}

\sepfootnotecontent{b}{In main file.}
\subfile{child}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

`child.tex`

```
\documentclass[subfiles-sepfootnotes.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\sepfootnotecontent{a}{In subfile.}

Some text with footnotes in
subfile\sepfootnote{a}, with
endnote\endnote{In endnote.}
and in parent
file\sepfootnote{b}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It dawns on me, could it be that `sepfootnotes` gathers content before `subfiles` includes the subfiles? Would that be circumventable?

Comment: On a side note, notice that the `sepfootnotes` package also provides endnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to scope: notes defined in a **subfile** are not available to the main document because in the subfile they must be defined within a `document` environment, and are thus restricted to it.

In order to circumvent this, you may insert `\global` right before `\@namedef` (not `\sep@namedef`) at lines 134 and 145 in `sepfootnote.sty` (v0.3b) to give your note definitions global scope. But I can't guarantee anything in other contexts.

Comment: Ahh. So, If I use end notes, then the `\theendnotes` command want access to the locally "def'ed names" and since they're def'ed in local scopes it doesn't work?

Comment: Sweet! Works like a charm. are you Eduardo, the maintainer of `sepfootnotes`? Is this an issue and a solution you might consider to incorporate in future releases or is the scope considered a wanted feature?

Comment: Yep, that's me. I'm not sure about incorporating it to the package. There is a trade-off here between making `sepfootnotes` compatible with `subfiles`, but then making it impossible for users to have notes defined locally. I have think about it. At any rate, thanks for drawing my attention to this issue!

Comment: Using an option, `scoped`? only since you know the solution. `sepfootnotes` is a gem. Having a unruly mind I'm using tons of notes. TeX code is kind of tiresome to decipher with notes all over the place. Thanks for making my life easier.

Comment: (It makes mine easier too.) I might introduce a `global` notion instead. This would break fewer documents. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also, I've asked a question ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319856/)) about the safest way to implement this `global` option. Would you test the new code (based on David Carlisle's suggestion) with your `subfiles`, please? I don't have any actual documents using `sufiles`.

Comment: I'll be glad to. Let's see if I have the time tonight. Otherwise; first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @Mats: Thanks. A new `sepfootnotes` (v0.3c) is available [here](http://latex.phi.pro.br/pkg/sepfootnotes-0.3c.tar.gz). Please be so kind as to tell me whether version 0.3c works with more complex documents using `subfiles`. I will submit it to CTAN as soon as I hear from you.

Comment: Oh, ha ha. I started editing my own `sepfootnotes.sty`. Sure. I'll check it right away.

Comment: And it is a go. The new `global` option works fine on a 20-subfiles-project which won't compile without it. Great Eduardo.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the feedback. I've already uploaded version 0.3c to CTAN. It should be available for update within 24 hours.